# missing libusb-1.x to install openOcd to use picoprobe

Tags: windows, pi-pico, troubleshooting

I am trying to set up a picoprobe in order to program my rp pico using only wires (using another rp pico). I am following these [instructions](https://datasheets.raspberrypi.com/pico/getting-started-with-pico.pdf#page=58&zoom=100,153,0) in Appendix A. I have windows 11 at the moment.

When i try to configure openOcd

```
./configure --enable-picoprobe --disable-werror
```

I get the following error.

```
configure: error: libusb-1.x is required for the Raspberry Pi Pico Probe
```

How can i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

On Linux, I had to install the -dev libraries in addition to the user libraries.